# input.next() keeps waiting for an input

Tags: java

Note: My code is written in Java.

I am making a reaction time test which works completely well otherwise. However, when I press enter it continues to wait for an input, which makes the reaction time test less effective. What should I write so that the Enter Key can be taken as an input rather than having to type a character then press enter.

Comment: You can use `next()` method and it's actually preferable especially if you are also using any of the other **nextFoo()** methods like `nextInt()` or `nextDouble()`, etc. But, to consume the newline character from the ENTER key hit you should also utilize the `useDelimiter()` method with the Scanner object, for example: `Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\\R");`. By doing this the `next()` method will act very similar to the `newLine()` method. A good rule of thumb is: ***If you are going to use `nextLine()` then use it for everything otherwise, don't use it at all.***

Comment: Oh...the `\\R` expression supplied to the `useDelimiter()` method above is for matching any Unicode line-break sequence, that is equivalent to `"\u000D\u000A|[\u000A\u000B\u000C\u000D\u0085\u2028\u2029]"`.

Comment: So, you add the useDelimiter() method and then keep next()? This seems simple enough

Comment: Correct, you can then keep using the **Scanner#next()** method.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `input.nextLine();`

Answer (score -1):

You can write `input.nextLine()` which returns whole input except for the line separator, as it finds line separator it skips the input.